# Windows Phone 8 SDK source code

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is Microsoft release some source code about Windows Phone 8 SDK? Actually I encounter some exception stack like

> at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.GetItemSize(Int32 currentOffset)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.TranslateVerticalPixelDeltaToOffset(Double delta)
>   at 
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IPixelBasedScroller.TranslateVerticalPixelDeltaToOffset(Double delta)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.UpdateManipulationOffsets(Point dragDelta)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.OnViewportChanged(Object sender, ViewportChangedEventArgs args)
>      at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
>      at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)

without source code I don't know where is the exception happened exactly. As an Android developer before, I found that it's really desperately when meeting some problems like this which I cannot find the source code. So, please enlighten me.

Comment: I don't think there is any plan to release the SDK code anytime soon. May be you can show us more of your code where this exception occurs.

Comment: You should submit a bug via [connect.microsoft.com](http://connect.microsoft.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Phone 8 SDK is not open source and I don't think Microsoft has any plans of making it open source anytime soon. So, what you want to do is not possible. I would suggest that you follow the advice of [AD.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/users/693272/ad-net) and [Shawn Kendrot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1054961/shawn-kendrot) that they provided in their comments. But as for your question of how to get access to the SDK source code, you will not be able to do this.